# Grails - Catch the URL before the action is complete

Tags: url, grails, controller, action, parameters

From within a random controller's action, I would like to access the URL the action is about to return (via a redirect if that matters) from within the action itself (parameters included of course). Would this be possible ? 
If it is... how ?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well....an action doesn't really *return* a URL, it returns content and/or some kind of HTTP status (404, redirect, error). If you want to modify the response of an action, your best bet is either an `afterView` or `after` [filter](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.6.2%20Filter%20Types)

Comment: Ok.. Thank you once more. 
And staying on the subject of URL catching: is it possible in Grails to catch the URL of the current page, parameters included ? 
Because **request.forwardURI** and **request.requestURL** both exclude the parameters from the catching.

Comment: Have a look at the API docs for `HttpServletRequest`, there are methods that provide access to every part of the URL, The `request` implicit variable in Grails controllers, GSPs, etc. refers to the current instance of `HttpServletRequest`

Comment: :) We always think ourselves really stupid when the response was right in front of us all the time and we just could not see it. 
The "getQueryString()" method of the indicated Interface did the trick. Chery on top of the thank you this time.